# CodedUI - ApplicationUnderTest does not launch all the associated DLL's

Tags: c#, coded-ui-tests

I have to test two softwares A and B and both communicate between each other. If I launch them manually there seems to be no problem but if I launch them via ApplicationUnderTest in CodedUI there seems to be an error and Software A says there is a communicaiton Error. I have heard that ApplicationUnderTest does not launch all the dll's that are associated with the specific Application. Is there a work around for this problem?

Comment: First verify that this is your actual problem. Get a process analyzer or monitoring program and check if the required dlls are loaded.

Comment: I used ProcMon and a com dll is not shown. my app itself is throwing an error saying Com dll's are missing

Comment: Does the test system copy the files somewhere before running the tests? If so, make sure it copies all the required files.

Comment: Okay now when i click run tests then it gives that problem but if i do debug tests then there is no problem. This is pretty hilarious ... I dont know whats wrong

Comment: Check your Test Results folder for the latest test and check all required dll's are present. There is no workaround for dependencies.